# Create Zip file for multiple images c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, zip

In my requirement I am converting docx to images its working fine but I need to store that converted multiple images into Zip file. Zip file was created successfully but Images are not opening it show corrupted/damage. Please try to help me to solve this solution. please refer my below total code. I used using Ionic.Zip; for creating a zip file.

```
         //Opens the word document and fetch each page and converts to image
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window window in doc1.Windows)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Pane pane in window.Panes)
            {
                using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    var pngTarget = "";
                    for (var i = 1; i <= pane.Pages.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var page = pane.Pages[i];
                        var bits = page.EnhMetaFileBits;
                        var target = Path.Combine(startupPath.Split('.')[0], string.Format("{1}_page_{0}", i, startupPath.Split('.')[0]));

                        try
                        {
                            using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])(bits)))
                            {
                                var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                                pngTarget = Path.ChangeExtension(target, "png");
                                image.Save(pngTarget, ImageFormat.Png);
                                zip.AddEntry(pngTarget, "Img");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        { }
                    }

                    // CREATE A FILE USING A STRING. 
                    // THE FILE WILL BE STORED INSIDE THE ZIP FILE.


                    // ZIP THE FOLDER WITH THE FILES IN IT.
                    //zip.AddFiles(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\users\\chaitanya_t\\Downloads\\"), "Images");

                    zip.Save(@"c:\\users\\chaitanya_t\\Downloads\\encoded.zip");  // SAVE THE ZIP FILE.
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: For the sake of efficiency, you may want to just do that `startupPath.Split('.')[0]` _once_ and save the result in a local string variable.

Comment: This link may be helpful.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: BTW startupPath.Split('.')[0] should be exchanged by Path.Combine( Path.GetDirectory( startupPath ), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( startupPath )) which will do the right thing at any startupPath and will also describe your real intention

Comment: 1) Since .NET 4.5, zip functionality is built-in to .NET in [System.IO.Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx), so the only reason why you might use a 3rd party library are for zip features that are not supported. You might get more help if you do it the standard way. 2) The file is being saved on disk in `image.Save` and then entry added from memory in `zip.AddEntry` - there doesn't seem to be much point in saving on disk if you are not going to use it.

Comment: Let's ignore the Zip part of this for a second. Can you simply try to write the image bytes `EnhMetaFileBits` out to a file and see if that works properly?

Comment: Also, are you sure it's not bitmap bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the stream position at the begin of the stream before processing:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])(bits))){
 ms.Position = 0; // Set stream position at the begin of the stream
 var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
 pngTarget = Path.ChangeExtension(target, "png");
 image.Save(pngTarget, ImageFormat.Png);
 zip.AddEntry(pngTarget, ms.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: any other solution please